# 2 columns of Floating imgs with differing heights left and right

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am having problems floating 2 columns - only 2 columns not 3 columns as other questions have been posed - of images so they fit together without gaps (like masonry, but without masonry js). I keep thinking I have it working as it will work for a couple of images but not for others.

I have tried column-count, but this aligns posts down each column, I need the posts to align horizontally. Reading left to right.

It is looking like this

[image]

I've tried adding in clears (left/right, every nth etc all combinations) by adding in a `<div class="clear"></div>` after 2 images and using nth-of-type or nth-of-child etc etc but no combination I have found seems to work for every thumbnail.

Why can't I get it so every nth-of-type (for example) goes left if odd or right if even?

[Here's my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goldengonaz/7637hag3/4/)

My CSS looks like this:

```
.container {
    width: 848px;
}
.thumbnail_small:nth-child(odd) {
    margin:0 0px 8px 8px;
    width: calc(50% - 12px);
    float:left !important;
    display:block;
}
.thumbnail_small:nth-child(even) {
    margin:0 8px 8px 0px;
    width: calc(50% - 12px);
    float:right !important;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: U can use column-count css property: http://jsfiddle.net/7637hag3/5/

Comment: @izorgor That isn't a solution unfortunately. I need it to read left to right, column-count aligns posts down the first column then down the next column.